# How can I cancel Steam's cloud sync?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

Is there a way to cancel a Steam cloud sync upload and start a game before it finishes syncing? **I don't want to permanently disable cloud sync.**

Situation:

- Play a Steam game.
- Exit the game.
- Decide to resume the game a few minutes later.

Problem:

- Steam cloud sync is still uploading my save file.
- Steam refuses to start the game before the save has finished uploading.
- I wish to play the game.
- I am sad and angry.

I tried:

- Disabling cloud sync for the game. This didn't seem to stop an in-progress upload.
- Exiting Steam. There's a message displayed about the cloud sync, but the "exit anyway" button is disabled.

<sub>Context: I'm playing Factorio (notoriously large savefiles) in a connection with slow upload. It takes a good fraction of an hour to finish a sync.</sub>

Comment: Regarding exiting Steam when it's trying to sync: I find that if I leave the pop up box for about 3-10 seconds, the "exit anyway" button will be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I found those instructions to disable Borderlands 2 (I don't know if Factorio) from synchronizing save data with Steam Cloud [here](https://gearboxsoftware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205280370-PC-How-to-Disable-Steam-Cloud-Save-Game-Synchronization):

- In your Steam Library, right-click on Borderlands 2 and select "Properties."
- Click the "Updates" tab.
- Uncheck "Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for Borderlands 2."
- Click "Close."

I imagine you already tried that, but it's all I found. If there's no other solution that's a pain in the ass, I assume save time will get even longer as your map keeps expanding, so I guess Steam will fix that for you if you ask, since it's their fault you can't really enjoy such a great game.

Good luck!

Comment: "*so I guess Steam will fix that for you if you ask*"  You don't know Valve very well, do you? ;)

Comment: Lord Gaben can surely fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "should" not "will" fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to play in offline mode, provided the game is capable of that as some games will not be.

Next would be force closing Steam rather than exiting it normally. This will cause Steam to "crash", and may corrupt some internal configuration data and cause loss of settings ranging from the categories you've applied to client settings. Could also theoretically cause the save to fail to be written, but I've never had/heard of that. This method though leaves you with the game open, which could be it's own mess.

Next would be temporarily disabling Steam Cloud for the game while playing. The simplest way to do so would be through the UI of course. You can also open `Steam/userdata/{Your Steam3.accountID}/7/remote/sharedconfig.vdf` and find the Apps section, and then find the game by it's appid and add the line "cloudenabled"  "0" (must be separated by two tab characters, and not spaces as tabs either).

Any time you're messing with the Cloud you'll have an increased chance to run into the "Steam Cloud Conflict" dialog which will ask to replace local files with the cloud version, or the cloud version with the local files. If this happens look carefully at the date of each option to help find which is older, because if you overwrite data it's not recoverable except possibly locally (which would still require a data recovery tool and be it's own level of insanity, and is unlikely to work since the machine will likely overwrite at least a part of the save data while doing so).